# Why does Playscape SDK not find JDK?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, playscape

Upgrading to Playscape SDK 1.7 on our Unity 4.5.4f1 game build, I receive the following error as the 'Moving final package' process of the build (for android) executes:

```
Playscape Misconfigured
To configure Playscape Publishing Kit go to Window > Playscape Publishing Kit Configuration...

- [WARN-G006] Please make sure you have a suitable JDK Installation.
```

The thing is the previous versions of the Publishing Kit had no issues locating the installations of Java on the system, including JDK 1.8 and 1.7, x64 versions. The PATH and JAVA_HOME variables have not been altered, why this seems to be a case where the Playscape SDK fails to find Java, or I am missing something obvious about configuring the Playscape SDK. What else can this error message be an indication of?
We do have the proper API key in place, a functional Java Heap Size and I have tried building with both Playscape Exchance and ARMEABI on and off.

Comment: Have you tried the same without relying on the variables and instead configured like you are told to ?

Comment: I am not certain I understand what you mean by 'configured like you are told to'.

Comment: I meant `To configure Playscape Publishing Kit go to Window > Playscape Publishing Kit Configuration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this specific issue was that something (as in, one of the components) now required me to have a JDK_HOME variable defined in my environment variables in Windows 7.
Adding the JDK_HOME variable and pointing it to a recent installation of JDK (for example "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51" solved the issue.